# how to get windows product type(home, professional or ultimate) from linux?

Tags: linux, windows

My windows is installed in another disk, dual boot.

how to get windows type from linux? any text file to check?

Comment: A useful question but might fit better on http://superuser.com. Which version of Windows do you have (Vista, 7, 8)?

Answer (score 0):

You might get windows product type from **/boot/grub/grub.cfg**, Try to execute follwing command from linux

```
cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

In that you may find windows version/type.